# C# - Attach file in Outlook Inline Message

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to attach a file in Outlook Inline Message Window(Reply, ReplyAll or Forward) with a new button in the ribbon.

Currently using VSTO C# to develop it

The button is working if it's a new mail window, but when I select a mail from the inbox folder it does nothing.

Checking with System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine("Text 1"); I can see it's not working this part of the code:

```
public void addAttachment(string valueText)
        {
             Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
             MailItem mailItem = _app.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;

             if (mailItem != null && mailItem.Class == OlObjectClass.olMail)
             {
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailItem.Subject) || mailItem.Subject.StartsWith("Untitled Message"))
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the inspector 1 " + mailItem);
                     mailItem.Attachments.Add(valueText); // --> This is working fine
                 }
                 else if (mailItem.Subject.StartsWith("RE:") || mailItem.Subject.StartsWith("FW:"))
                 {
                     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is the inspector 2 " + mailItem);
                     mailItem.Attachments.Add(valueText); // --> This is what is not working
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine("Unknown window");
                 }
             }
        }
```

The idea is when I click the button in the ribbon it will run a custom script and after this will take a file to be attached in the new mail automatically (It can be a New Mail Full Window or just select an email and click Reply, ReplyAll or Forward).

**EDIT:** I tried to find it by Subject.StartsWith, but not working, it seems like there is not ActiveInspector when I use these buttons

[image: Reply, ReplyAll and Forward Buttons]

Comment: Can you try to check subject when you reply or forward ?

Comment: Also `MailItem` has `Parent` property. I guess for reply you can check that.

Comment: I edited the post, I already tried to use the subject but seems like the buttons are not calling any inspector

Comment: What project did you choose ? so I can try to reproduce. 
Because this code is not looking like Outlook VSTO Add-in project.

Comment: I'm using "Outlook VSTO Add-In", I created a Ribbon(XML) then I added there this part of the code

Comment: I was reading documentation about it and it seems this part is named "Actions in reading pane", still looking for information about how to call those buttons from script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your VSTO add-in there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance:

```
Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
```

Instead, you can use the `Application` property of your add-in class (see `ThisAddin`). Also you can access the `Application` instance anywhere by using the static `Globals` class, see [Global access to objects in Office projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Calling the `ActiveInspector` method doesn't make any sense in case of inline emails:

```
MailItem mailItem = _app.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem;
```

Instead, you need to use the [ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property to get the item opened inline in the `Explorer` window:

```
MailItem mailItem = _app.ActiveExplorer().ActiveInlineResponse;
```

The property returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane.

Also you may find the [Explorer.InlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.inlineresponse) event helpful which is fired when the user performs an action that causes an inline response to appear in the Reading Pane.

Comment: This is perfect, it's what I need.
The only thing what is left is: I need to use both, Inspector(for New Mail) and Explorer(For inline Response)
I'm trying to figure how to mix them in an If sentence

Comment: Try to use the `ActiveWindow` property which returns an `Explorer` or `Inspector` window depending what is active.

Comment: I'm trying to use it but I don't know how to get the output of ActiveWindow() to set the filters (I'm beginner in C#, this is my first project and I learn from Zero, still trying to learn how to use lot of things)

Comment: I think your initial question was answered as the caption states. In that case I'd suggest asking new questions in new threads, so users could easily recognize questions and answers.